# Unable to navigate to another page using PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data in the database. As i give the email and password it should fetch the database and login. The problem is, from loginform.php file it is navigating to the loginvalidate.php file, but after that it doesn't navigate to another page which I have mentioned in the header() function. As soon as i give the email and password, and hit the login button, it just stops at loginvalidate.php and doesn't proceed to profile.php file. I hope you get it.I donno where the error is, it is neither throwing an error. I'm using WAMP and when I run this code in the browser, the url should display ../../profile.php after hitting the login button, but it shows ../../loginvalidate.php in the URL and the page has nothing to show i.e blank. I have used the md5 function to store passwords in the database. So here also first I have applied the md5  function on the user entered password and then used the password_verify. Is it the password verifying problem or is it anything else ?

**loginform.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="includes/loginvalidate.php" method="post">
        <div style="margin-top:17%;">
         <!--Text box to enter email-id-->
            <input id="email" type="email" name="eid" placeholder="E-mail" required/>
            <hr style="position:relative; color:white;">
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:3%">
         <!--Text box to enter password-->
            <input id="pwd" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
        </div>  
            <div style="margin-top:15%">
                <input type="image" class="mclass" name="loginbt" id="login"  src="images/login.png">
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**includes/loginvalidate.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx","yyy","zzz");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if(isset($_POST['loginbt']))
    {
        $errmsg='';
        $email =$_POST['eid'];
        $pass = md5($_POST['password']);

        if($errmsg == '')
        {
            $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT id, email, password from users WHERE email = :email');
            $sql->bindParam(':email',$email);
            $sql->execute();
            $result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($result)>0 && password_verify($pass,$result['password']))
            {
                header('location: ../profile.php');
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("Username/Password is incorrect")';
                echo '</script>';
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

?>

Comment: Add ini_set('display_errors',1) as the first line of the page that is showing up blank.  This will let you see what the error is.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Plz debug your code by **echo or die**

Comment: If I use ini_set('display_errors',1); it is still not throwing any error @user2182349

Comment: No Deepak, I'm not getting any error.

Comment: Is `<?php` the very first thing in your loginvalidate.php file? No spaces, no linebreaks...

Comment: Yes julio, no spaces, no linebreaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all folks, I've found the solution myself. I usually thought that the code I have written was a bit complex. Then after some 99 failed attempts and for 100th attempt, I found the solution myself. This is how loginvalidate.php file should be

**includes/loginvalidate.php**

```
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx","yyyy","zzzzz");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        $email =$_POST['eid'];
        $pass = md5($_POST['password']);            
        $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT id, email, password from users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password');
        $sql->bindParam(':email',$email);
        $sql -> bindParam(':password',$pass);
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->fetchColumn();
        if($result == true)
        {
            header("Location: ../profile.php");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            echo '<script type=text/javascript>';
            echo 'alert("Username/Password is incorrect")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
```

ob_end_flush();

I would like to thank each and everyone here who have helped me to find the solution but the main credit finally goes to myself. :P.

Comment: Glad you solved it and it is nice you posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are using an image type to submit but testing it as if it was a submit type...

```
<input type="image" class="mclass" name="loginbt" id="login"  src="images/login.png">
```

This won't bring

```
$_GET['loginbt']
```

as you expect

So it is failing the test here:

```
if(isset($_POST['loginbt']))
```

The image as a button work in the sense that it submits the form. But if you need to test for a value coming from that form you could test any other element or create a hidden element with the name/value that you want to test.

```
<input type="hidden" name="loginbt" value="loginbt">
<input type="image" class="mclass" id="login" src="images/login.png">
```

For instance. This way the info won't show on your form but will be sent to the server

You should also always use a "secret", never repeated value in a hidden field to check if the POST is comming from a real form (google XSS protection).

Comment: I tried your way of approach, so the thing is, though I type the correct password, it is executing the else condition, i.e username/pwd is incorrect.

Comment: So then this qestion is answered. (a green ticket is welcome :) )
The password test is another thing.
I can't tell if the password or the e-mail you used to retrieve it are correct but that MD5() looks wrong since you are using password_verify()... did you try withou hashing it first or comparing without password_verify? You must do accordingly to what you did when you saved the password there.

Comment: So julio, just for testing case, i removed the md5 function and tested, it's not navigating to another page, but is there any alternative for password_verify() ?

Comment: For testing purposes... do `if(true) { header('location: ../profile.php'); exit();             }` when you realize whether navigation to another page is your issue or not... you go back to debuging you password storage implementation.

Comment: got the problem, that's the issue now, whether it is checking that if condition or not, it is not entering into this following condition, if(count($result)>0 && password_verify($pass,$result['password'])){}

Comment: check the fisrt condition  `count($result)>0`. assuming the email is right it should pass. It is overkilling anyway... `if($result) would do it but it's ok as is. I think the second condition is the problem. Check code where you store the password in db. If you've created the password with `password_hash(md5($_POST['password']))` it should work as is. If you haven't used `md5()` there, you should not use it here either. If you haven't `used password_hash` there, you should not use `password_verify` here and do a simple compare `md5($_POST['password']) == $result['password']`... good winds

Answer (score 0):

Using your form code, then using

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Shows

> ["loginbt_x"]=> string(1) "0" ["loginbt_y"]=> string(1) "0"

So, you can test for either of those values like so

```
if (isset($_POST['loginbt_x']))
```

and it should work.

When an image input is used to submit a form, the input names sent to the server, are an _x and _y, which refer to the position of the cursor on the image when it was clicked.

Comment: I didn't get you, can you explain briefly ?